# Updating code based on 3.5 Framework that uses PIA for office 2007 to work with Office 2016

Tags: .net, excel, visual-studio, office-interop

I am using Visual Studio 2008 with 3.5 .NET Framework over an ERP product. There is an implementation of PIA libraries for Office 2003, 2007 so that Excel can be integrated with the ERP.

Now the issue is that the client has changed Office and now uses 2016 ver. Is there a  solution for this ? Can I use Microsoft Office Object Library 16.0 over 3.5 framework working product ? Any help is useful ! Thanks !

Comment: If this is integrated with the ERP product I think you'd have to ask the manufacturer of that product whether it's limited to certain sets of PIAs and versions of the .NET Framework. There shouldn't be any problem using .NET 3.5 with the Office 2016 PIAs as long as we're not talking VSTO, just straight-forward interop. You don't mention the programming language, which affects how simple it would be for you to switch to late-binding instead of using the PIAs, but that would be another option.

Comment: I just started new with this Project and didn´t do enough digging before asking the question. Sorry for that, here is the situation, it looks like the previous programmer used Office Web Components 2003 in order to embed Excel spreadsheets  to edit inside .NET ERP. I found several third-party APIs that work with Office 2013 but none for 2016. Is there any workaround for this ? Third-parties APIs that support Office 2016 ?

Comment: Requests for third-party tools are off-topic on Stack Overflow - read the information in the [help] on asking questions. (And no, I haven't a clue about either OWC or other tools of this type.)

Comment: Thank you for your answers.